# What is wrong with this MySQL insert statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginning php/mysql developer, and I have written this statement to insert a username and password into a database to make an account. For some reason I am getting an error though; what's wrong?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO signup (Username, Password, Email) VALUES ($username, $password, $email)") or die ("cnnot run query");
```

Comment: Always include the actual error in your questions.

Comment: this query should work fine. did you check the database column names?

Comment: You should probably read [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html), and [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Comment: it just returns "cnnot run query"

Answer (score 3):

Put quotes around the $username, $password and $email.

You should use prepared statements. Such usage is prone to SQL injections

Comment: Yup, it should be   `mysql_query("INSERT INTO signup (Username, Password, Email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')") or die ("cnnot run query");`

Answer (score 0):

Check your database connection code. Yes as Zimbabao suggested, always put quotes. here's sample.

```
//connect and select db
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("databasename") or die(mysql_error());

//Now Insert 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO signup (Username, Password, Email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')") or die(mysql_error());
```

The error you are showing is custom, if still getting error - please mention what does mysql_error() gives?

Comment: sorry, tried using mysql_error() and it returned "No database Selected"

Comment: Now it works. But now it shows a blank space in localhost phpmyadmin.

Comment: it appears that you are not getting form post data in your variables. do check whether you are actually getting data on the variables or not.. test with echo $username; echo $password; echo $email before writing query. later you can remove test code. if you are not getting data in these variables you have to double check the form variables or form post values.